# Delegate and Datasource for second Collection View

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, storyboard

There is a second UIcollectionView in my app, which is having an imageview.
But every-time I get an error like this

```
Thread 1: "could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier SliderCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard"
```

Where `SliderCell` is the Id of first `UICollectionview`

I know that this is because the identifier is not registered / misspelled. and I tried registering. But the same error happens.

What I found is when I add the delegate and Datasource of the second CollectionView to the same View, this error happens.

is there any solution for this?

Comment: Yes. I am already using to diss. tags for them and using collectionView.tag to return values accordingly. (in both cellForItemAt and numberOfItemsInSection fns.)

Comment: Is the second collection view using slider cell, a different custom cell or UICollectionViewCell?

Comment: Both CollectionViews are similar , one cell and one imageView. second cellis having a diff, ID

Answer (score 0):

[Solved]

Before :
first I declared `dequeueReusableCell` method for both cells, set the cell values and put the `return` statement in an `if-else` condition.

After:
all three lines for first collectionView in `if` and declared other in `else`